# syncing maps cross platform on xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, geolocation, synchronization

I am developing an app using **xamarin native** and it will be cross platform and will have native maps ( uwp bing map for uwp, and google map api for android , same for ios ).
the Feature it will have is **live location of a user on the map**, ( like **uber** ). multiple users in a group will be able to see each other's live location on the map while they are moving. some of them might have an iphone, some will have android and some might have windows phone. So irrespective of devices obviously they must have same experience.

> So my question is how can I sync maps on each device together, for this feature to work properly, or can I use only google maps on all 3 platforms?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  There is no reason you would have to use the same map on each platform.  But you will need some sort of central server to track and sync the locations of each user.  There are many different ways you could approach this - there is no single "right" answer.

Comment: then kindly list the simple and possible way I can do this. I am new to using maps and I have to know the approach before I start development so that I can decide architecture of my app

Comment: @touseef A mile high view: Have each user/app/device post its continuously updating location to a "realtime" database, that database pushes changes to all other registered users, as those changes are received by the app, you update the map with their new location... Databases like Google's Firebase database work well in this use-case. Hire me, I've done this before, hahahahahahahaaa

Comment: @SushiHangover haha thanks a lot this helps, I will be using any db from Azure probably, If I had budget to hire you, do you think I would be asking this question here ? :P I am single developer who is trying to do everything in building this app actually. Plus by location you mean coordinates right? If I sync the value of the coordinates it would work fine for all maps? I mean the same value of coordinates will give same location on all? or do I have to convert the unit or something?

Comment: map coordinates are universal lat/long values and should work with any map type

Comment: @touseef  `location you mean coordinates`? Yes, lat/long (and other info, i.e. a user id, etc...), `work fine for all maps`? Yes, lat/long is **the** global standard

Comment: thanks to both of you  
also @SushiHangover  Please put this as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: @SushiHangover if you have time and if you dont mind can I discuss some architectural questions with you regarding this problem? you have done this before so you might be able to help me in that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mile high view and yes, opinion based since I wrote an tracking app like this before:

- Assign users/devices to a tracking group
- Have each user/device post its continuously updating location to a remote "realtime database"
- Database publishes changes to all other subscribed users within that tracking group
- As those changes are received by the app via a subscription, push notification, client polling (bad...), you update the map with their new location...

Note: The backend "Database" can be a composited of many things and I am not necessarily talking about a traditional SQL box, but a cloud-based pipeline.

- A Publish / Subscribe No-Sql database like Google's Firebase database is ideal for this use case as you can maintain history if needed, assign users to groups, it is JSON-based so client integration is easy, you can integrate it w/ Mobile Push notifications via Functions (non-server-based) for users that do not have the app running, etc.. This makes the hosted/cloud/backend design simple.
- You mentioned Azure, so you should review "Azure Service Bus" as it supports one-to-many in a publish/subscribe pattern. It does not by default store history, but you could have a global subscriber that is an cloud-based agent (vs. a client/device) that can react to location changes if needed, have it log locations to a database (SQL or NoSql-based, depending upon the volume of location changes, etc...).

Not promoting Google products, but they now have a "Transport Tracker Solution" that came out a month or so ago that packages this entire use-case into a product, it requires a Google Map Premium Plan ($$$). You should review their Google Developer YouTube video and guides for that product as you can "gleam" a lot of information about how they do it and items that you might not thinking of, be should be...

- https://youtu.be/1cOIm7n5V54
- https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/

Comment: Brilliant answer and well explained . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please have a look at this question I just posted, maybe you get an idea of approach, I am trying to do. plus the reason I want to use azure is bcz I just got a bizspark subscription, and I can use azure for free uptil a certain limit, and ive been a C# developer for a long time and Microsoft products support it everywhere, here is link to my other question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452685/continuous-database-sync-with-azure-functions