# continuous database sync with azure functions

Tags: database, azure, synchronization, azure-functions, serverless

I am developng an app with xamarin and azure **serverless** functions as backend for the app.
I will be **syncing map coordinates** from the users in real time with a **database on the cloud**. i.e : taking coordinates from all users and then pushing the updated coordinates to all users at the same time, **continuously** so that all users can see live location of each other.

> So I have to call an **azure function** in **continous loop** in order to sync database with cloud. so it can check db after every, 4-5 secs. is it the best way to do this? or will this cause too much execution of azure function and might be costly? If there is a better way to sync the db please suggest. Thankyou.

Comment: Look at "Brokered messaging" using Azure Service bus with a one-to-many Topic/Subscription as a start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview You can also invoke an Azure Function based upon an message begin added to a queue (`ServiceBusQueueTrigger`). You do not want to try continuous loop an Azure Function, at that point spool up an instance and have it do your continuous dirty work.... ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover
spool up an instance of what? :P an azure call can maximum last upto 5 mins. but my continuous work will probably can be upto an hour or so, means I have to continuously track the geolocation of a group for longer time, that time is not fixed, it can be variable,

Comment: Spool up a "VM" instance (or a Docker container) that is running your code.... But you could use Azure Service Bus and you do not have to have any custom code running in the cloud, each client/device publishes it changing location to the bus via a topic and all the clients that have subscribed to that topic receive those location changes. Now one of those "clients" could be a VM or Docker container that is also doing something with those locations, or you have an Azure Function that is invoke for each published location (via ServiceBusQueueTrigger) and you could push it to a log, database, etc

Comment: and if I dont need to log them I dont need an azure function or a VM/Docker at all right? secondly how does the azure service bus cost? does it cost like a VM ( constantly running) or does it cost like function (only charge for specific topics sent)?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

Answer (score 2):

You have a mobile app that is making http calls to azure functions. Functions is elastic and scale will likely be fine. As I understand, you're *not* asking how to implement the server side of this; rather the real question here is pricing, right?

Azure Functions can run in two ways:

1. "serverless", aka "Consumption plan". In this case, Azure Functions is managing the underlying server (and scale out) and **you pay only for active usage (per GB*Sec)**.  This is what you get by default when you visit http://functions.Azure.com.  See pricing details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/
2. "AppService" - In this case, you've bought a VM upfront and you decided how much to scale. **You pay a fixed monthly cost**. See pricing details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

You can switch between them. I'd recommend starting with the first approach. It will certainly be cheaper in the beginning when you have low traffic. Monitor cost, run your scenarios through the pricing sheets, and consider switching to the 2nd if it ends up being cheaper.

Comment: I do know about both pricing systems in functions, the reason I asked is if I run azure functions on loop in consumption plan it will cost a lot, and if I run it in App service plan it will run sometimes and sometimes it wont hence causing extra cost. So I am trying to find a loop hole to do my scenario without spending extra, plus I am not using mobile app, I want to use a complete serverless backend, hence using azure functions as complete backend.

Comment: But you don't need a constant loop here - this is demand driven by calls from your mobile clients. Ie, your client will be making http calls to the server to a) update its location; b) ask about other locations. 
 So during testing and initial roll out, you'll have low traffic and #1 will be cheapest by far.  You can then use the pricing charts to calculate at what point you may want to switch over to #2.

Comment: yes your are right in start traffic will be low. actually the I will be needing continuous live geolocation from multiple users ( clients ) in a group, i.e: I have to get their location and send them to server about after every 5 secs or so. and I need to do this for about an hour or 2 continuously, the time may vary, that is why I am asking bcz if I call the function only once it will take coordinates of that time, but again after 5 seconds I would need to execute function again to get the new coordinates of that user, right?

Comment: Correct. But these calls are all client-driven; so don't think of the server as being in a "continuous loop". The server is just responding to (many) client calls. And you're just looking for the optimal pricing plan to handle that workload. 
That said, you very likely want to find a means to reduce the network chattiness here (for example, don't have every user communicate with every other user)  - but that's another question.

Comment: oh ok thnks.. :)